# config.py did not send back DATABASE_URL

Tags: flask, environment-variables, flask-sqlalchemy

my config.py:

```
"""Flask config."""
import os
from dotenv import dotenv_values

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

configuration = dotenv_values(".env")

class Config(object):
    DEBUG = False
    TESTING = False
    CSRF_ENABLED = True
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL')

class ProductionConfig(Config):
    DEBUG = False
```

I'm trying to connect to DB with another py file:

```
import psycopg2
import xlrd
from config import Config


POSTGRES = Config.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
connection = psycopg2.connect(POSTGRES)
cursor = connection.cursor()
```

But POSTRES is None

my .env file is in same directory like this:

```
FLASK_APP=wsgi.py
FLASK_ENV=development
SECRET_KEY=randomstringofcharacters
DATABASE_URL='postgresql://xxx:xxxxx@127.0.0.1:5432/xxxxx'
```

All my files are in same directory.

Comment: So is it POSTGRES or POSTRES ? You could simply add a print in your config section right after declaring POSTGRES to verify that it is indeed has a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dotenv_values()` doesn't side-effect the local environment. You need `load_dotenv()`, which does.

See https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/#load-configuration-without-altering-the-environment